# Yii find all relation of a model

Tags: php, yii

I'm dealing with Yii framework and I have a little question about find.
This is my situation:

I have a model user and a relation user->friends. So, to get all the friends, I just need to do $userModel->friends. And this will return an array containing all the user model that are his friends. Now, what I want to do, is, given a list of user, loop over it, for each user check if this user is a friend. I know I can user User::model()->exists, but how? I'm a bit lost here.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why not to put your `relations()` code here? If `friends` relation itself has defined options by which another User **is** a friend, you do not need to check this again. Just traverse friends

```
foreach ( $userModel->friends as $friend ) {
    var_dump( $friend );
}
```